# Reading values from properties file

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to read a property file in a seperate "GetConfigProperties" class file and passing the value to the main function "LoginTest.java". But I am not able to get the expected property value and there is no errors displayed in the code as well.

I have the property file in  src/config.properties
I have the main function in src/com.automation.test -> LoginTest.java
I have the java function to read property file in src/com.library.helper -> GetConfigProperties.java

My code to read Config property is given below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties; 

public class GetConfigProperties {

//protected File file = new File("config.properties");
protected static Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = GetConfigProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

    public static String extractUrlData(){
    String webUrl = props.getProperty("webUrl");
    return webUrl;
    }
}
```

--
Also, I imported this class file in the main LoginTest.java and try to access the get the data as GetConfigProperties.ExtractUrlData() but failed.

P.S - I looked into many of the questions and answers and since I am totally new to Java couldn't understand them as everything seems to be unique.

Comment: In order to be environment-independent, you should get it from classpath, not from filesystem.

Comment: Define "I am not able". What happens when you run the code? What do you expect to happen? What is the code using this class? Why are you initializing a static field of a class from a constructor of this same class?

Comment: @JBN: that's not a constructor, just a badly named method (which is yet worse though). It's by the way surprising (and sad) that a 12K and 3K user with `[java]` as their top tag didn't even know how to get an input stream of a simple resource from the classpath by the class loader.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, i agree it is a badly name method and I amended it to "GetPropertiesFileStream". I initially mentioned as below and then amemded it by looking into different stackoverflow issues...                                                    protected File file = new File("config.properties");

Comment: `File` is not designed to get resources from the classpath. It is designed to get files from filesystem. You have it in the classpath already (at least, by default, everything in IDE's `/src` folder ultimately end up in runtime classpath), so just get it as a resource from the classpath by the class loader, you could even get the resource directly as input stream.

Comment: @JBN : I just have one value in the property at the moment in the config.properties file and it is : [webUrl="http://google.com"]  and I want that value of webURL to be returned in the main class. *P.S : text in the property file will be without that square braces, just to highlight i added it in the comment

Comment: @BalusC: good catch. My mind is so used to naming conventions that it skipped the `void`.

Comment: @BalusC: I removed the code to to initiate "file" and "fis" and changed the props.load as below:                                                                   props.load(GetConfigProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));                                                                but still getting null value :(

Comment: Note that the properties file has this way to be in exactly the same package as `GetConfigProperties`. Look at JBNizet's answer, it has a leading slash, it would load the resource from the root of the classpath (say, from the "default" package). This should work provided that `/ProjectName/src` is indeed the root of the classpath as represented by the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you access the properties:

```
GetConfigProperties.ExtractUrlData();
```

This calls the **static** method `ExtractUrlData()` (which should be called `extractUrlData()` to conform to Java naming conventions). Nowhere do you call the `GetConfigProperties()` method of `GetConfigProperties`, which is where the Properties object is populated.

You should choose: either the Properties is static, and it should be populated when the class is loaded, by a static method, or a static block:

```
private static Properties props = createAndPopulateProperties();
```

or it should be an instance field, that can be populated by the class constructor or one of its instance methods that would initialize the object.

Another problem is that there is a very low chance that the user running your app has the file in exactly the same folder as you (if he's even running Windows). You should bundle the properties file with the .class files of the app (in the same jar, or the same directory), and use the class loader to load the resource:

```
InputStream is = GetConfigProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

Comment: Many Thanks JBN. I removed that badlyNamedmethod method totally as it is not required now and replaced them with your InputStream. But could you let me know What should I do now to retreive the value based on the keyword .. in my case, need to extract "http://google.com" using "webUrl"  **P.S - I amended my initial question description to reflect t recent changes

Comment: You forgot to load the properties from the input stream: `props.load(is)`.